# Why my transition out doesn't work for alert v-model in Bootstrap-vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

So I am new to Vue and checking some classes and now I learn transitions. I copy pasted the css code below from Vue official transitions and it doesn't work!But only the fade out!The fade in is fine.
Extra problem is the v-model  for some reason v-if doesn't work at all.

```
<template>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Animations!</h1>
        <b-row>
            <b-col>
                <b-button @click="showAlert = !showAlert">Show Alert</b-button>
            </b-col>
            <b-col>
                <b-alert variant="warning" v-model="showAlert" key="1">Wanrning!</b-alert><br>{{ showAlert }}
            </b-col>
            <b-col>
                <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
                    <b-alert variant="primary" v-model="showAlert" key="2">Animated Wanrning!</b-alert>
                </transition>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                showAlert: true
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
    .main{
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }
    .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Ok found the problem! <b-alert> bootstrap doesn't take v-if in so if I take it to html alert it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap you alert with a `div` element and use `v-if` for render it conditionally :

```
 <transition name="fade">
          <div v-if="showAlert">
            <b-alert variant="primary" v-model="showAlert" key="2">Animated Wanrning!</b-alert>
          </div>
</transition>
```

check this [example](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/bGpVzVx)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `<b-alert>` is removed from the DOM when it isn't shown. So the transition doesn't get to play out.

You can get around this by dropping `v-model` and using `v-if` instead, combined with the `show` prop.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      showAlert: false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.16.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-btn @click="showAlert = !showAlert">Toggle Alert</b-btn>
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <b-alert variant="primary" show v-if="showAlert">
      Animated Wanrning!
    </b-alert>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! that was really helpful cause I want to keep using bootstrap-vue for practice